# Restricting the position of an image to the viewable area in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

So I have this script to move around an image. But I want to make it so I cant move the bottom of the image above the bottom 60 pixels.

```
function right(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1; // get just the number and not the units
    document.getElementById(id).style.left = current - 5 + 'px'; // taking advantage of JavaScript's strange but sometimes useful type conversion. The subtraction converts it to an int and the addition converts it back to a string. 
    document.getElementById(id).src = 'guyr.png'
}

function left(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.left = parseInt(current) + 5 + 'px'; // here we can't use that trick
}

function up(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.top.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = current - 5 + 'px';
}

function down(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.top.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = parseInt(current) + 5 + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to detect the height of browser:

```
var myHeight;
if( typeof( window.innerHeight ) == 'number' ) { 
  //Non-IE    
  myHeight = window.innerHeight; 
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) { 
  //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode' 
  myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientHeight ) ) { 
  //IE 4 compatible 
  myHeight = document.body.clientHeight; 
}
```

Then, you can set condition :

```
if(current > myHeight - 60) {
  // do your function
}
```

Comment: no i would like to make it so that the object being moved can not go above 60 pixels from the bottom.

Comment: Kudos for providing support all the way back to IE4.

Comment: yeah you can just adjust the height value with the 60 pixel offset by taking the 60 pixels of the height of the actual browser window.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var myHeight;
if( typeof( window.innerHeight ) == 'number' ) { 
  //Non-IE    
  myHeight = window.innerHeight; 
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) { 
  //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode' 
  myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientHeight ) ) { 
  //IE 4 compatible 
  myHeight = document.body.clientHeight; 
} 
if(current > myHeight - 60) {
  // do your function
  document.getElementById('img').style.top = '30'
}
</script> doesnt work to keep my img down